# making json object with array in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

I've got some database query.
At the end I need a json object like this

```
    [{
      activity_type:'Develoement',
      spent_time:[
        {user:'User1', time:'21'}, // (!) amount of time for this user and this activity
        {user:'User2', time:'2'},
      ],
      total_spent_time: 23
    },{
      activity_type:'Design',
      spent_time:[
        {user:'User', time:'14'},
      ],
      total_spent_time: 14
    }]
```

Here is my while loop of the sql-query

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                $data[$row['activity_type']] = array('spent_time' => 
                    array('user' => (object)$row['user']));
                $data[$row['activity_type']]['spent_time']['user']->time += $row['spent_time'];

            }
```

but in a result array I have

```
        [Design] => Array
        (
            [spent_time] => Array
                (
                    [user] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [scalar] => John
                            [time] => 1.5  // (!) only the last activity time, NOT the sum of spent time for this activity
                        )

                )

        )

    [Developement] => Array
        (
            [spent_time] => Array
                (
                    [user] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [scalar] => Nick
                            [time] => 0.3 // (!) only the last activity time, NOT the sum of spent time for this activity
                        )

                )

        )
```

How do I sum the value of time in a loop for current user and current activity?

UPD
Here is the query

```
$sql = "SELECT 
                distinct(projects.name) as project,
                time_entries.hours as spent_time,
                enumerations.name as activity_type,
                versions.name as version,
                users.lastname as user
                FROM  `projects` 
                INNER JOIN time_entries ON ( time_entries.project_id = projects.id ) 
                INNER JOIN enumerations ON ( time_entries.activity_id = enumerations.id ) 
                INNER JOIN versions ON ( projects.id = versions.project_id ) 
                inner join users on (time_entries.user_id = users.id)
                where (projects.identifier = 'test')";
```

Comment: why are you mixing objects and arrays together when you can simply make an associative array to solve the issue.

Comment: because it doesn't sum the values of a spent time, does it?

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: that "json" is just for example

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like...

```
    class ActivityList{
        private $activities;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->activities=array();
        }

        public function addActivity($row){
            //read the row, search for the activity
            //if does not exist, create a new activity
            //if does, get it and use addUser to add more time
            ...
        }
    }

    class Activity{
        private $activity_type;
        private $spent_time;
        private $total_spent_time;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->spent_time=array();
            $this->activity_type="";
            $this->total_spent_time=0;
        }

        public function addUser($user, $timeSpent){
            //search for the user in spent_time
            //if not exist, create a new user
            //if exist, add the time
            //once added, take the time and add to total_spent_time
            ...
        }
    }

    class UserObject{
        private $user;
        private $time;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->user="";
            $this->time=0;
        }
    }
```